# Falty Makefile causes undefined reference and multiple definition errors

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm on my path to study the wonderful world of Makefiles and this was my first attempt on my own makefile. However I have hit my small brains at a wall with errors and I can not figure the cause, I only know the issue is in the Makefile, I am doing something wrong, because when I compile my "project" manually, it compiles.

```
cxx := g++
dirs := obj bld_win32 bld_linux
cpp := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
obj := $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(cpp:.cpp=.o)))

ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
    target := bld_win32/engine.exe
    flags := -mwindows -lopengl32 -openal32 -lgdi32
else
    target := bld_linux/engine
    flags := -lX11 -lGL -lopenal -lalut
endif

all: precheck $(target)

precheck:
    mkdir -p $(dirs)

$(target): $(obj)
    $(cxx) -std=c++11 -Wall -o $@ $^ $(flags)

obj/%.o: $(cpp)
    $(cxx) -c -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern rule is wrong, as you would have noticed if you'd tried to build object files one by one using this makefile. This rule:

```
obj/%.o: $(cpp)
    $(cxx) -c -o $@ $<
```

lists *all* source files as prerequisites of *every* object file, and when you try to build *any* object file, it compiles only the first source file in the list (`src/aardvark.cpp`, or whatever), so that all of your object files are the same, even though they have different names.

Change it to this:

```
obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
   $(cxx) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Yes, silly me, I forgot to manually test compiling the objects. Thank you a lot!